# Make UITabBar items ALL look unselected

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBarController` with a `UITabBar` in my iPhone app. I would like to remove the "selected" look of the current viewcontroller, so they all have the same black tint. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Theres no logical concept for having non of the tabs selected. And apple has not built a function to deselect all tabs.

Comment: Do you mean, you still want the icon colour to be different, but the rest of the background of the tab bar to remain the same colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a while back ago. You can remove the whole thing and draw it again? I think that´ll work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with iOS 5 there is now UIAppearance which will let you customize the looks of standard controls. BUT, and that is a very VERY BIG BUT: why? Seems odd to say the least.